# In my Cocoa screensaver code, how do I terminate?

Tags: cocoa, screensaver

In a standalone app, I would do `[NSApp terminate:self]` but for a screensaver bundle, this actually terminates the SystemPreferences app, which is bad.

So, in my Cocoa screensaver code, how do I terminate the screensaver?

Comment: Why do you want the screensaver to terminate itself? This isn't how screensavers are generally meant to work. There may be a better mechanism for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/92726-can-screensaverview-quit-itself.html), one can propagate a mouse event which will exit the screensaver. From inside the screen saver view, one simply has to call:

```
[super mouseEntered:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simulate a keystroke so the screensaver exits. Not sure what the code is in Cocoa, though.